# Replace certain elements in a list of matrices with equal structure

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of several matrices which all have the same 11*19 structure but different values in them. In each of those matrices I want to replace the values in certain elements with "NA".
It is working for one single matrix:

```
m1<-matrix(seq(1:209),11,19)

m1[1,1:19]<-NA
m1[11,1:19]<-NA
m1[1:11,1]<-NA
m1[1:11,19]<-NA
m1[2,1:5]<-NA
m1[2,15:19]<-NA
m1[10,1:5]<-NA
m1[10,15:19]<-NA
m1[3,1:4]<-NA
m1[3,16:19]<-NA
m1[9,1:4]<-NA
m1[9,16:19]<-NA
m1[4,1:3]<-NA
m1[4,17:19]<-NA
m1[8,1:3]<-NA
m1[8,17:19]<-NA
m1[5,1:2]<-NA
m1[5,18:19]<-NA
m1[7,1:2]<-NA
m1[7,18:19]<-NA
```

It is not working anymore if I want to do this to a list of matrices:

```
m2<-matrix(seq(209,1,by=-1),11,19)
m3<-matrix(seq(210,418,by=1),11,19)
m_list<-list(m1,m2,m3)

m_list[1,1:19]<-NA
m_list[11,1:19]<-NA
m_list[1:11,1]<-NA
m_list[1:11,19]<-NA
m_list[2,1:5]<-NA
m_list[2,15:19]<-NA
m_list[10,1:5]<-NA
m_list[10,15:19]<-NA
m_list[3,1:4]<-NA
m_list[3,16:19]<-NA
m_list[9,1:4]<-NA
m_list[9,16:19]<-NA
m_list[4,1:3]<-NA
m_list[4,17:19]<-NA
m_list[8,1:3]<-NA
m_list[8,17:19]<-NA
m_list[5,1:2]<-NA
m_list[5,18:19]<-NA
m_list[7,1:2]<-NA
m_list[7,18:19]<-NA
```

Is it feasible with apply or a related function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `list` we can use `lapply`

```
lapply(m_list, function(x) {x[1, 1:19] <- NA
                            x[11, 1:19] <- NA 
                            x
             })
```

NOTE: We can use most of the assignments as showed in the OP's code.

Comment: But then only the elements of the first matrix are replaced, the other two matrices are unchanged.

Comment: @curbholes It is changing the elements in all the matrices.  Remember that you changed the first matrix before you placed in a list.

Comment: My bad: I forgot to assign the result to the variable m_list. In the end it works out well! Thanks!

Comment: Why is the single "x" needed at the end of the function? Does not work without that one.

Comment: @curbholes It is to return the changed matrix.  If you don't do that, then it will return only the single NA for each list element.

Comment: Ok, I guess it is the same as return(x). Thanks again!

Comment: @curbholes Yes, it is the same.  In `R`, you don't need to explicitly say `return`